# Consuming data from an Azure IoT hub

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-sdk

I have devices sending data to an Azure IoT hub regularly (Not Azure Event hub).

I am trying to write something in Python running on the cloud which waits for these events / messages to arrive and then store data in a database.

There are classes and APIs for the Azure Python SDK which consume data from **Event Hubs** such as  `EventHubConsumerClient.receive`

However. I am limited to just using an IoT hub in this case.

What can I do to consume / ingest data from an Azure IoT hub? I'm a little bit lost with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

An IoT Hub uses an Event Hub under the hood and exposes an endpoint for that:

> IoT Hub exposes the messages/events built-in endpoint for your back-end services to read the device-to-cloud messages received by your hub. This endpoint is Event Hub-compatible, which enables you to use any of the mechanisms the Event Hubs service supports for reading messages.

See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-read-builtin) on this topic.

So this means you can use the Azure SDK for Python to read data using the Event Hub classes. To get started follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-python#read-the-telemetry-from-your-hub) Python based tutorial.